# PHP/MySQL: fetch one result

Tags: php, mysql

This is my database:

[image: database]

This is the query:

> SELECT * FROM users

Now when I do this:

```
$query = $connection->query($_GET['query']); // SELECT * FROM users
print_r($query->fetch_assoc());
```

I get this as output:

> Array (
>       [id] => 3
>       [username] => karel )

Why does it not output id 4 and username ccscs?

When I a while loop:

[image: whileloop]

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you don't give any order to your query so it automatically get first record. If you want to return last record you can order by id desc as follow

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC
```

If you instead need to retrieve all records you will need to loop throw your records

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Based on new op info i would not fetch twice but one as follow

```
$fields = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    print_r($row);
    $fields[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: This would return the last record, but I think the OP wants to get all rows.

Comment: That's why i placed both solution

Comment: Use second solution then, loop throw all records.

Comment: Don't fetch result twice, just do both operation in the same loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's because  [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) just fetches one row.

To get each row you can do it like this:

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
   print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Still one line: while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
       print_r($fetch);
      }

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please show us the output. If you mean that every row has a single line is normal.

Comment: @user3144435 That's because of this `for` loop you placed before. It already retrieved the first line and the `while` loop just gets the rest. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: Do you mean the foreach loop? Thats to get the field names, when I remove that it works but now I could not get the fieldnames anymore.

Comment: You will need to write a own query for get the field names, or you could get the names in the first iteration of the while.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch_assoc()` retrieves a single row from a result set. [See here](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc).

> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row
> as an associative array

You should use something like this :

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
   print_r($row);
}
```